Why cython gives error on global function without arguments?
I have a function in python as follows.
##############################
def queryPythonVersion() -> str:             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    return '3.11'

Cython then generated the following C code.
 /* "src/CnTestingTask.pyx":2
 * ############################################################# CnTestingTask.pyx #############################
 * def queryPythonVersion() -> str:             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     return '3.11'
 * 
 */
  __pyx_codeobj__1343 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(0, 0, 0, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_src_CnTestingTask_pyx, __pyx_n_s_queryPythonVersion, 2, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__1343)) __PYX_ERR(0, 2, __pyx_L1_error)

Then cython gives the following warning and error messages.
build_cythonize\src/CnXXX.c(1754397): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' and 'int'  differs in levels of indirection from
build_cythonize\src/CnXXX.c(1754397): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 14
build_cythonize\src/CnXXX.c(1754397): warning C4047: 'function': 'int' and 'PyObject *'  differs in levels of indirection
build_cythonize\src/CnXXX.c(1754397): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 15
build_cythonize\src/CnXXX.c(1754397): error C2198: 'PyCodeObject *PyCode_New(int,int,int,int,int,PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *,int,PyObject *,PyObject *)': Too few arguments to function

The original warning and error messages contain Chinese.  I tried my best to replace them to English.  Hopefully it is more readable globally now.
Can someone give me advices on this?  What is the reason for the warning and error?  How should I modify this code or change the way of using cython to avoid the problem?
Thanks

Since the error messages you've posted are in Chinese, and this is an English-speaking site, you're probably in a better position to tell us the reason for the errors.

Hi, dear Khelwood, I tried my best to change those Chinese messages to English by google searching parallel posts.  Hopefully that it is OK now.

You are probably trying to use an old version of Cython with a new version of Python which it wasn't designed to support. But since you don't tell us this information we can't know for sure

I am sorry that I think I misunderstood the messages of cython.   The c code generated by cython is in fact associated with commented python script below it, not above it.  But the misunderstanding was somewhat caused by the layout of the commented python scripts and the generated c code.  There is no blank line between the c code and the above commented python script.  But there is a blank line between the c code and the under commented python script.  So I thought in the last day that the c code is associated with the above commented python script.
